# Not possible to pass UDT between modules on different projects

Tags: excel, vba, project, user-defined-types, office-2007

I believe that what I'm about to ask is a restriction but I am hopeful that there is a satisfactory solution.

I am working with multiple files / workbooks and am intending to keep code associated with the data as much as possible. Therefore I want to be able to link from one procedure to another across projects.

I would like to be able to pass my arguments in a user-defined type when linking but have come up the following compiler error:

**Only user-defined types defined in public object modules can be coerced to or from a variant or passed to late-bound functions**

What I've found is that I only get this problem when I use *Application.Run* not when I issue a *Call* statement. However, I could not get *Call* to work across projects. Subsequent reading seems to confirm this. (I did read that *Application.Run* does not pass *ByRef* and it is also evident that UDT's can only pass *ByRef*). So it seems I'm lumbered. Here is some sample code to illustrate the point

```
Option Explicit

Public Type type1
  s As String
End Type

Public Sub main()

Dim t As type1

Application.Run "Book2!Freda", t

End Sub
```

Application.Run "Book2!Freda", **t**
is where the compiler error occurs

Comment: You could consider converting your Type to a class.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25013024/only-public-user-defined-types-defined-in-public-object-modules-can-be-used-as-p

Comment: Thanks for the link, Tim , and apologies for not spotting this question before submitting my own. I was hazily aware that I could do something with classes but have been hesitant to dip my toe into the OO pool just yet. In for a penny; in for a pound, I suppose