# VBA Pass Array of Array from Function to another Function

Tags: excel, vba, function, jagged-arrays

I have defined the following data structures:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

'Data related to coupon ---> these are the attributes
Public Type CpnData
    'coupon info
    cpn_no_prime As Integer
    cpn_no As Integer
    'departure info
    dep_airpt As String
    dep_date As Date
    'arrival info
    arr_airpt As String
    arr_date As Date
End Type

'Coupon numbers --> these are the coupns
Public Type cpnNo
    cpn_nbr() As CpnData
End Type
```

And then use these in the following function to return an array of array

```
Public Function FetchCpnData()
    
    'Declare varbs
    Dim wsCpn As Worksheet
    Dim tkt As cpnNo
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim cpnCnt As Integer
    Dim iRow As Integer
    Dim lRow As Integer
   
    'Assign varbs
    Set wsCpn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("tCpn")
    cpnCnt = wsCpn.Range("F1").value
    iRow = 2
    lRow = wsCpn.Cells(Rows.count, "G").End(xlUp).row
    i = 0
    
    ReDim tkt.cpn_nbr(cpnCnt)
        For i = LBound(tkt.cpn_nbr) To UBound(tkt.cpn_nbr)
            ReDim Preserve tkt.cpn_nbr(i)
                With tkt.cpn_nbr(i)
                    .cpn_no_prime = wsCpn.Cells(iRow + i, Range("tCpn_Nbr_Prime").Column).value
                    .cpn_no = wsCpn.Cells(iRow + i, Range("tCpn_Nbr").Column).value
                    .dep_airpt = wsCpn.Cells(iRow + i, Range("tCpn_Dep_Airpt").Column).value
                    .dep_date = wsCpn.Cells(iRow + i, Range("tCpn_Dep_Date").Column).value
                    .arr_airpt = wsCpn.Cells(iRow + i, Range("tCpn_Arr_Airpt").Column).value
                    .arr_date = wsCpn.Cells(iRow + i, Range("tCpn_Arr_Date").Column).value
                End With
        Next i
        
End Function
```

I then want to pass this jagged array to a UDF that will be entered in the cells, with the ability to loop through that array

Assume that the function that I want to access that array from:

```
Public Function Cat12DateRange(eff_fr_yy As String, eff_fr_mm As String, eff_fr_dd As String, _
                               eff_to_yy As String, eff_to_mm As String, eff_to_dd As String, _
                               tvl_prt As String, btwn995 As Long, and995 As Long) As String


    'Declare varbs
    Dim tkt() As cpnNo
    Dim i As Integer 'loop through coupon array
```

Am i declaring tkt() As cpnNo in the wrong function?

Comment: `FetchCpnData` doesn't return anything.

Comment: The data structure should be tkt>cpn_nbr>cpn_nbr(1)>attributes, then tkt>cpn_nbr>cpn_nbr(2)>attributes, so on.

Comment: I changed ```Dim tkt() As cpnNo``` to ```Dim tkt As cpnNo``` in Cat12DateRange and called the FetchCpnData function by ```Call FetchCpnData(tkt)``` and then in FetchCpnData added ```FetchCpnData(ByRef tkt As cpnNo) As Variant```  which appears to be working

Comment: Your function should return a value using `FetchCpnData = tkt` as the last line, then you call that from `Cat12DateRange` :  `Dim tkt as cpnNo: tkt = FetchCpnData()`  Your Type names might be easier to work with as `Coupon` and `Coupons` though...

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for your reply, is it incorrect to call the function by name and pass tkt to it as above?

Comment: It's not "wrong", but it's not really following accepted practice - a function should *return* something, otherwise it should probably be a Sub.

Comment: @TimWilliams great. Thanks for your help. I will update with your recommendation

Comment: It looks like your  FetchCpnData method is reading in a block of data from a spreadsheet.  If your columns are contiguous you can assign the range directly to an array.  If they are not contiguous then I think you first need to define a union then assign to an array.  To work with column in the array I'd define an Enum for the column names.

Comment: @TimWilliams I did as you recommended above, however I got the following compile error: Only user-define types defined in public object modules can be coerced to or from a variant or passed to late-bound functions. Any thoughts?

Comment: There are some restrictions on how you can use a custom Type in VBA - to be honest I almost never use them.  You'll find your life is easier if you instead define them as custom Class modules instead.  Eg see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25013024/only-public-user-defined-types-defined-in-public-object-modules-can-be-used-as-p